# enlarge multiple pages / vertical equivalent of addmargin

Tags: geometry, page

Is there a command to enlarge multiple pages, similar to `\enlargethispage{}`?

I use `KOMA` classes: a vertical equivalent to `\begin{addmargin}` could be useful if it exists.

Ex.

```
\enlargepage{2cm}
pages are enlarged here
\enlargepage{0cm}
pages back to normal
```

Comment: `\clearpage\addtolength\textheight{2cm}`

Comment: BTW, addmargin doesn't actually change the margins, but rather uses negative indentation.